# Unity SyncVar string too long?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It seems there is a hard limit to the size of a string I would like to sync. I'm programmatically creating a `Mesh` on the server and then using `MeshSerializer2` to turn it into a string. I would like to sync this string over the networks and user `MeshSerializer2` on the client to create the `mesh`.

I'm getting error when I run the code.

> IndexOutOfRangeException: Serialize(string) too long: 280416

Any idea how to sync a Mesh over UNET?

Comment: The serializer returns a byte array. Cut that array in smaller pieces and reconstruct the array on the receiving end. The sending method also passes an order ID so you can reconstruct in order on the other side. Here it is : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1113376/unet-send-big-amount-of-data-over-network-how-to-s.html

Comment: @fafase that comment is complete enough to have been a full answer. You should have posted it.

Comment: I still can do it though :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serializer returns a byte array. Cut that array in smaller pieces and reconstruct the array on the receiving end. The sending method also passes an order ID so you can reconstruct in order on the other side.

Here it is : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1113376/unet-send-big-amount-of-data-over-network-how-to-s.html